# Jquery getting the tab to add a class when active

Tags: javascript, jquery

All of this works except for trying to get it to apply the class 'current_tab' to the 'ul.tab_nav li' when the 'ul.tab_nav li a' is clicked.

JQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.tabs').each(function(){
    var tab = $(this);
    tab.find('.tab_content').hide(); // Hide all divs

    tab.find('ul.tab_nav li a').click(function(){ //When any link is clicked
        tab.find('ul.tab_nav li a').removeClass('current_tab'); // Remove active class from all links
        tab.addClass('current_tab'); //Set clicked link class to active

        var currentTab = tab.find($(this).attr('href')); // Set variable currentTab to value of href attribute of clicked link

        tab.find('.tab_content').slideUp(); // Hide all divs
        $(currentTab).slideDown(); // Show div with id equal to variable currentTab
        return false;
    });
});
});
```

and html

```
   <div class="box tabs siteBackgroundColor">
    <div class="box_header">
        <ul class="tab_nav">
            <li class="dummyTab"><a href=".tab1" class="iconTab">&nbsp;</a></li>
            <li><a href=".tab2" class="iconTab iconTabWifi">&nbsp;</a></li>
            <li><a href=".tab3" class="iconTab iconTabWeb">&nbsp;</a></li>
            <li><a href=".tab2" class="iconTab iconTabHours">&nbsp;</a></li>
            <li><a href=".tab4" class="iconTab iconTabMap">&nbsp;</a></li>
            <li><a href=".tab3" class="iconTab iconTabPhone">&nbsp;</a></li>
            <li><a href=".tab4" class="iconTab iconTabShare">&nbsp;</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="box_content tab_content tab1 dummyTab"></div>
    <div class="box_content tab_content tab2">
        <p><span class="textBold">HRS:</span> Mon-Fri 7am to 3pm, Saturday 8am to 3pm <span class="textBold">KITCHEN CLOSES</span> at 2:30pm</p>
    </div>
    <div class="box_content tab_content tab3">3<br />
        3<br />
        3<br />
        3</div>
    <div class="box_content tab_content tab4">4<br />
        4<br />
        4<br />
        4<br />
        4</div>
</div>
```

Besides that it's working the way I need it to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this,

```
tab.find('ul.tab_nav li').removeClass('current_tab');
$(this).closest('li').addClass('current_tab'); //Set clicked link li to active
```

**[Demo 1](http://jsfiddle.net/rohankumar1524/HznC9/1/)**

To Set the `active` link only then try,

```
tab.find('ul.tab_nav li a').removeClass('current_tab');
$(this).addClass('current_tab'); //Set clicked link class to active
```

**[Demo 2](http://jsfiddle.net/rohankumar1524/HznC9/2/)**

In Place of

```
 tab.addClass('current_tab'); //Set clicked link class to active
```

**Updated** you should use `hide()` in place of `slideup()` which will not animate the closing `div` and check the `active tab` if it is your `current_tab` then use `return false` for that `anchor click`

**[Demo 3](http://jsfiddle.net/rohankumar1524/HznC9/3/)**

Comment: I've got a couple more questions, just been told that there will be more than one tab box on the page.

First Question:
Is there a way to make an open tab automatically close when a tab in another tab box is clicked?

Second Question:
When an open tabs anchor is clicked it jumps back up then down, is there a way to make it close when a 'Current_tab' anchor is clicked?

Thanks for the help so far,
Hopefully you can help me out with the rest.

Thanks @Rohan

Comment: How can I do the same with my code here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25392223/how-to-show-or-hide-tab-based-on-the-page-url

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing  the following code

```
tab.find('ul.tab_nav li a').removeClass('current_tab'); // Remove active class from all links
tab.addClass('current_tab'); //Set clicked link class to active
```

with

```
tab.find('ul.tab_nav li').removeClass('current_tab'); // Remove active class from all links
$(this).parent().addClass('current_tab'); //Set clicked link class to active
```

Fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/HMS37/

Answer (score 0):

I edit in your code for you can learn easily:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.tabs').each(function(){
        var tab = $(this);
        tab.find('.tab_content').hide(); // Hide all divs

    tab.find('.tab_nav li a').click(function(){ //When any link is clicked
        tab.find('.tab_nav li').removeClass('current_tab'); // Remove active class from all links
        tab.addClass('current_tab'); //Set clicked link class to active

        var currentTab = tab.find($(this).attr('href')); // Set variable currentTab to value of href attribute of clicked link

        tab.find('.tab_content').slideUp(); // Hide all divs
        $(".currentTab").slideDown(); // Show div with id equal to variable currentTab
        return false;
    });
});
});
```

Comment: use this tab.find('ul.tab_nav li').removeClass('current_tab'); at the place of tab.find('ul.tab_nav li a').removeClass('current_tab');

Comment: How do I use your code for my issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25392223/how-to-show-or-hide-tab-based-on-the-page-url